# How to fix bounds of a PopoverViewController, when presents a actionSheet (AlertController)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

When a ViewController presents a actionSheet (AlertController) in iOS 8 way by UIPopoverPresentationController, the ViewController shrinks its bounds to size of the actionSheet.

What I tried to do is showing a actionSheet on a popover, but I do it in iOS 8 way, I got this weired situation.

This is how I got this situation"

1. It pops the ViewController by UIPopoverPresentationController, when pressed a barButtonItem. (As image 1)
2. When pressed the button on the ViewController, it presents a actionSheet
3. Then the ViewController shrunked its size to size of actionSheet. (As image 2)

And here is the whole project for reference.
https://github.com/allenlinli/ALtryEverything/tree/Q435235
It's in the project "TryAlertOnPopoverOnBarButtonItemOniPad".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `preferredContentSize` for the navigationController in ViewController.m

like this:

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
{
    // ....
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:historyViewController];
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    navigationController.preferredContentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    // ...
}
```

The preferred content size for any container view that is laying out a child view controller.

reference: [Apple UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW133)

Comment: Why is action sheet in iOS 8 square.  Above fixed the popover resizing issue.  But in popovers on iOS 8 action sheet other buttons have square corners.  You can see it in his screenshot above.  Only seems to happen in popovers.